# Android - Share browser url to app

Tags: android

I am writing an app for a community, which has the ability to share URLs.

In the android browser, there is the possibility to forward URLs, for example from my HTC Desire to a BlueTooth Target, to Facebook, to Friend Stream, to Google Mail, to Google+, Mail, SMS and Peep. What I want to achive is to add my app into that list, providing functionality to forward the current URL from the Browser to the App, regardless on which webpage I am currently.

How do I achive that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do this with [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html), with the action *SEND*. This filter will take plain texts, images and videos.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your activity you can check `getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)` to know you have been started as a send action and `getIntent().getType()` what type of data you got.

The data itself (Text, image or anything else) can be found via `getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)` or `getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)` (Depends on data type and the sending application).

Comment: No, that's not what I am searching for. The Android Browser has a menu to forward URLs to several services. There I want to dock in to forward the current opened url to the app.

Comment: Yes, I want something like the user is searching something on google via android about his pet and finds something really interesting to share with his friends, in that case he should be able to go into the menu of the android browser, choose more, choose forward url and in that following list, there my app should appear for publishing that url. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Ok, i rewrote the answer. Still an intent-filter, but a totally different one :)

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I am searching for :)

Comment: @H9kDroid I want to know where we come from like sharing image from gallery , sharing text from browser in our app. How i can find I coming from gallery , browser?