# Android: I want my app to be on the 'Share via' list when user clicks Share in the Browser

Tags: android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Share browser url to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126299/android-share-browser-url-to-app)

I want my app to be added to the 'Share via' list when the user chooses 'Share' in Web Browser's (or Chrome's) menu. I expect the app to have the URL of the opened page passed to it from the Browser.

What exactly is needed to implement it? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126299/android-share-browser-url-to-app

Comment: @OlegVaskevich Thanks, I'm closing the question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement a share intent in order to implement the share menu. Check out [this](http://collegewires.com/android/2012/06/android-implementing-a-share-intent/) tutorial.